# unix statement runs fine manually but not via launchd or cron

Tags: bash

```
egrep -w 'TCP|UDP' ~/IPsDenied.txt | sed 's/:[^:]* in/ in/' | awk '{cmd="echo "$5" | geoIP | fgrep 'Country:' | cut -c 16-43"; cmd | getline rslt; close(cmd); print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "rslt}' >> ~/IPtoCountry.txt
```

Why doesn't the geoIP script in my statement get called when I use launchd or cron ? It runs fine manually ... I tried putting the complete PATH for geoIP
like `~/geoIP` or `./geoIP` or `/Users/Admin/geoIP`

```
#IPsDenied.txt
Apr 6 08:58:16 TCP 212.58.244.61:80 in

#IPtoCountry.txt
Apr 6 08:58:16 TCP 212.58.244.61 in United Kingdom
```

instead, I get just

```
Apr 6 08:58:16 TCP 212.58.244.61
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because cronjobs are often run with limited '$PATH's so try the same but giving the absolute path to your geoIP app.

Comment: Also, does the user running the cronjob have execute perm to /Users/Admin/geoIP ?